# Accessing workflowArguments in a hosted workflow 

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

We are mixing workflows, a workflow using receive activity's more at the end. But at the start we want to pass in some arguments (not using a receive activity!)

Our workflows are already being created and resumed using a dynamic endpoint with IWorkflowCreation and a class derived from WorkflowHostingEndpoint. In the OnGetCreationContext the creationgContext is filled with WorkflowArguments and the workflow runs. At a later part the receive activity's are creating a bookmark which can be resumed with a message. All seems nice.

But in a xamlx there are no WorkflowArguments, i understand why, except that i want them anyway. I though about an activity in which i can write some code to get the Arguments myself, but i do need some help here.

Or is there another way to pass along the WorkflowArguments into a xamls without using Messaging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass arguments into a starting workflow service except through the SOAP message that starts it. But there is nothing preventing you from reading any properties in your workflow service. So it is perfectly fine to do read settings or something similar instead of passing them in at startup.

Comment: Did u read my question or maybe didn't understand? The arguments are passed along the creationcontext in the dynamic endpoint to create the workflow. In there they are added to the workflowarguments collection.

Comment: Not well enough I guess. But the basic principal is the same. You need to pass the arguments in a roundabout way to your workflow. There is no simple standard way to do so but basically you store the arguments somewhere and retrieve them from within the workflow.

Comment: You are right, but how to pass them along into the workflowinstance? I though it was done by the WorkflowArguments that are passed along into the CreationContext in the OnGetCreationContext method within WorkflowHostingEndpoint. Or will they just be thrown away in case of an xamlx. I could work around by saving the arguments into a database at that moment and query them in a activity, but that feels like a hack :)

Comment: Sorry, Maurice, but you can pass arguments into a WorkflowServiceHost using the WorkflowCreationEndpoint and the CreationContext. Technically the root is no longer a WorkflowService but it is still hosted in the WFSH

Comment: Are you using Activity as your root type in that case?

Answer (score 1):

We have solved this exact situation by creating another WCF service which sits alongside our xamlx service on a slightly different url (e.g. /WorkflowMetadata) and this is where we implement a service method that returns a dictionary of string, type.

In the implementation of this service we simply read the xamlx and determine the arguments.

This is what we use to interrogate a target workflow in an activity designer when creating something like a launch-workflow activity.

Creating an activity will not work as that activity will need an instance in order to run. All you want is some metadata about the xamlx service. And if you are using a WorkflowCreationEndpoint to construct a creation context then you are probably only allowing a  dictionary of string, object as the start parameters. Therefore standard metadata will not work. This left us with the only option being to provide another service beside the workflow which serves metadata.

Background here: http://blog.petegoo.com/index.php/2011/09/02/building-an-enterprise-workflow-system-with-wf4/

Comment: That launch workflow activity calls a receive activity from the another workflow? Not something we can do easy with WIF enabled, then it would require another relying party delegation. Yes we are using WIF inside our workflows using an WorkflowExtension to store Principal that started it until a bookmark is hit.

Comment: Nope, it calls the CreationEndpoint on the other WFSH where the dictionary of values it passes will get mapped to arguments on the WF Creation Context. Not that I've used it but isn't the security activity pack designed to solve the auth problem?

Comment: Security is automaticly and hidden in our activity's. The end customer is allowed to be a less-tech user and the security pack is to complex as well as the receive activity's with correlation etc.

Comment: Can u postsome code to show how u solved this issue. PS: i'm not even sure if it's really the same issue.

Comment: I wrote a series of blog posts a while ago detailing our approach to the workflow initiation scenario. I've added the link to this in my answer above. The wcf service is simply a normal WCF service that loads the type (or xamlx), reflects (or parses) the arguments and sends a list of them back in the response.

Comment: Thats indeed the same problem, but... u used a receive activity to receive the Question and Email arguments. So thats what Maurice is saying, u can't pass arguments into a starting workflow service except through the SOAP message that starts it. That Receive activity creates the instance of the workflow. But +1 for the nice blog post :)

Comment: Yup, in the last EnterpriseWorkflowDemo.zip going for the Enterprise solution, i downloaded it and there are only xaml workflows. No xamlx workflows. In xaml there are WorkflowArguments accessable, but in xamlx they aren't. And we are mixing the workflows, customers are allowed to use Receive activity's but aren't forced into. A requirement is that we can't drop xamlx support and replace it with dynamic endpoints.

Comment: Yes, you are using xaml instead of xamlx as the actual workflow. It is an activity not a WorkflowService. This allows you to pass your arguments through using the CreationContext which will map them to the arguments you have on your activity. WorkflowServices do not have arguments, if you are set on supporting WorkflowService then you cannot have dynamic argument mapping as you would be changing the WCF operation contract. However you can still support Receive and Reply activities the Enterprise approach, they just won't support CanCreateInstance.